# How to pass arraylist of Objects to Promise in AWS SWF?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have an Employee class. In my workflow i want to pass array of Employees to the promise object. While passing the array of objects I am getting the de serialization Error. Kindly help.

```
Promise<ArrayList<Employee>> emp=new Employee().getEmployeeDetails();
```

Comment: From the code snippet it is not clear what happens in the getEmployeeDetails method. Unless it calls an activity serialization should never happen.

Comment: Can you provide the employee code snippet? Also just a pointer that if you are using default deserializers then you need to have at least one constructor in your class that has no parameters.

Comment: I am not calling activity serialisation. Can you please provide a sample snippet for activity serialisation?

Comment: It is impossible to help you without understanding what you are doing. The provided code snippet contains no information about how the Promise instance is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all that you are trying to achieve is to create a promise object then use Promise.asPromise method. It returns you a promise object which is available immediately. 
I hope you are using the flow framework provided by the aws sdk. The Promise class that I referred to above is from flow framework code